# Node Webshot Screenshot of Angular JS Page does not wait for page load

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am using node-webshot utility to capture screenshot of an angularJS based website.

I have the following code which is partially working.

```
const webshot = require('webshot');

var options = {
  streamType: 'png',
  windowSize: {
  width: 2048,
  height: 2048
},
  shotSize: {
    width: 'all',
    height: 'all'
  }
};
webshot('URL here', 'image.png', options, function(err) {
    if(err){
        console.log("An error ocurred ", err);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Job done mate :)")
    }
});
```

It works fine for simple websites like google.com e.t.c, but the only problem is that the angular js website i am trying to fetch information from loads the default page first, then loads some additional bits (Forms, UI stuff) e.t.c after few seconds since it makes some http calls in the background.

I have tried using renderDelay property and set it to a large value. it does wait for that time, but still image is just a blank image.

As per their doucmentation set this

> takeShotOnCallback   false   Wait for the web page to signal to webshot
>   when to take the photo using window.callPhantom('takeShot');

Now i can put this takeShotOnCallback in my properties above, but in the angular app, when i try to write this window.callPhantom, it gives me the error that method doesn't exist.

So how should i use this?

Another broader question is, does Node webshot is the right tool to capture screenshot for Angular 6 website. Or should i look for some other solution.